# Lightbox - Way to start without first image

Tags: lightbox

I have a lightbox that has one image, then some more images in the same set, but these are styled to be hidden, the only way you can see them is by clicking the first image (the only visible one) and activating the lightbox.

Is there a way of skipping straight to the second image in the lightbox instead of the image being clicked on being shown first,

This is what im working on:

http://yvonneestrada.com/taylor/gallery.php?id=5&start=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a link on the first image that will link to the second one. It may look something like this:

```
<a href="2"><img src="1" /></a>
<a href="2" style="display:none;"><img src="2" /></a>
<a href="3" style="display:none;"><img src="3" /></a>
```